# Bluetooth software doesn't find any device, bluetooth dosen't work and doesn't pair!

Tags: bluetooth

My Wi-fi works fine but Bluetooth doesn't.

I have the Broadcom BCM 943142Y. I have the latest driver installed but Bluetooth doesn't work with Ubuntu 14.10.

I found the Device ID's of the Broadcom cards on my machines by doing:

`# lspci -n | grep 14e4`

Mine is this one:  `43142 2.4 Ghz  0x14e4    0x4365`

I have also installed the precompiled binary from the Ubuntu repository!

Why doesn't the Bluetooth work? It works perfectly with windows 8.1 on same machine!

Please check out some commands I did to understand the problem:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11103986/

I had help from  WXL linux techniccian #Lubuntu  IRC official support channel from FREENODE server.

Comment: Well if it's a wifi card, then it speaks wifi, not bluetooth ( I tried googling the device and can't find any information on it ).

Comment: Your link has no info, please edit your question to include the results of `lsusb; uname -a; rfkill list all`

Comment: Jeremy31: Yes it have information inside it?

Comment: Psusi: Yes it is an hybrid wifi board with bluetooth. Of course the board got 2 separates devices on it, wifi and bluetooth.

Comment: @FilipeWritter  I think your bluetooth may just need firmware, if you look at the result of `lsusb` one may show as a Broadcom Bluetooth device and may look like `ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0`  Then search for the ID 0a5c:21e8 or whatever yours is and see if you can find a .hcd file